# error accessing the properties of an instance of a defined object

Tags: angular

Why do I get an error in this code ( which you must be familiar from the angular docs as the code is mostly the code there )

The error stems from the line with the stars...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };

  if (hero.name === 'prekazi') {  // <--******************
    // do something
  }
}
```

The error is

```
Failed to compile.

/Users/.../Desktop/angular-tour-of-heroes/src/app/app.component.ts (20,11): ',' expected.
```

It's due to this line:

```
if (hero.name === 'prekazi') {
```

Why can't we get to the property of the hero instance with the dot notation? Could someone kindly point me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is inside the class, but not inside a method of the class. For example, it works if you add it to `ngOnInit`:

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    hero: Hero = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Windstorm'
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.hero.name === 'prekazi') {  // <--******************
            alert('That\'s my hero! ')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right on! What a clown am I! Thanks for the catch! It's also working this way: `constructor () {
    if (this.hero.name === 'prekazi') {
      alert('That\'s my hero! ')
    }
  }`

Comment: But when I pass the expected bingo string 'prekazi', I'm NOT getting the alert! Does angular do the good-old js alerts in a different way?

Comment: @AverageJoe Yes the constructor is good too for this example. In general, I tend to use the hooks like `ngOnInit` since that's when all other data is available (like data being passed into the component via `Input`).

Comment: @AverageJoe The alert should be the same. Are you passing the `hero` into the component now? Or still creating it inline? Maybe you can create a live example?

Comment: You have set it to 'Windstorm' just before, it's not 'prekazi' so alert() is not fired

Comment: That's very true. After you guys point it, I can see it instantly where & why the failures are. It takes a little bit of time to wrap one's head around this.. as to what executes first and what later.  To test that alert, I guess I can set an even binding like (onchange) on the textbox and that tie that to a method within the AppComponent class and fire the alert from that method. Have  I started catching the drift?

Comment: @Frank , Hey Frank, do we no longer need to do the `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';` anymore? My code worked without it. When do we need to import OnInit if ngOnInit already works without it?

Comment: `OnInit` is an interface, so you only need to import it if you are implementing the interface explicitly by doing `export class AppComponent implements OnInit`. That way it forces you to have an `ngOnInit` method with the right signature. You happen to already have that method, but it would be good to implement the interface anyway for clarity and to prevent future bugs if you change the method in any way (you'll get a compiler error).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did this and the alert fired. `(change)="checkPrekazi($event)"; `  This has been a great intro. Thank you